# How to use Macbook terminal caffeinate to stop macbook from going to sleep while running Jupyter code on Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter

I'd like to keep my battery saving options but ensure my macbook is awake and running my code before it goes to sleep.

From what I understand, there is a command called caffeinate that does just this.

My Chrome has several windows / tabs. How do I tell the Terminal to focus specifically on the tab which is running my Jupyter code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `caffeinate` from the Terminal, start it at the beginning of whatever you're doing that you want to keep the computer awake for and stop it when you're done.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['caffeinate'])

try:
    pass  # Your big beefy computation here
finally:
    # Terminate caffeinate
    proc.terminate()
```